# What is the regular expression for zip code i.e. 96754-2222

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
 <input class="input-width" placeholder="XXXXX" maxlength="10"
  type="text" name="zip" ng-model="shipping.zip" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />
```

This is entering only numbers.how will I enter 5 numbers then '-' then 4 numbers. I am new to regular expressions. Can anyone help me in this to create this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches your requirements:

```
^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$
```

That is:

```
 characters 0-9
  |    5 of them 
  |    |
  v    v
^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$
         ^^^          ^ 
          |           | 
          |           group is optional
          |
group (no-capture)
```

See annotations. Also there is a literal `-` dash and `^` and `$` anchor at the beginning and end of string.

5 digits followed by optional `-` and 4 digits.

Comment: It worked exactly according to my need. Thanks for details. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Pallavi My pleasure, glad  I could help

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
pattern = "/^\d{5}-\d{4}$/"
```

`\d` is equally to [0-9] - matching every digit